# Ellipses should be done on client side or server side

Tags: css

I have to do ellipses on UI, My question is whether to do ellipses on client side or server side.One solution suggested by my team member is to so on server side, to calculate the number of character(by calculating the width of W) and the server side will then send the appropiate characters but the issue is if we dont have W, ellipses happen in middle of line.
We have to do ellipses in two lines.
Please suggest the best approach.

Regards,
Deepti

Comment: Well, since you mentioned the UI, do you think the UI should be done on the client side or server side?

Answer (score 0):

funny question...i think you want to ask its a ui thing or php thing but its just a small css job

for example you want to apply ellipsis for some heading(h1) then below css will work

**CSS**

```
h1{
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

width will define after what width ellipsis should come, overflow hidden prevents the text to show beyond the width, white-space will force the text to come in one line, and text-overflow will show you the ellipsis effect.

Comment: but that is not possible with css...in crome its possible with some more css but this will not at all possible with css in all browsers you have to use some logics with jquery...